# Disabling Legacy Option ROMs Disables Graphics Card

Tags: windows-10, boot, graphics-card, bios, uefi

I have a Dell XPS desktop with an MSI NVIDIA GTX 1060 graphics card installed.

What worked: Boot UEFI (Not Legacy) with Legacy Option ROMs set to Enabled and Secure Boot Disabled.

What I wanted to do: Set Legacy Option ROMs to Disabled (which is a prerequisite to set Firmware TPM to Enabled).

What happened: After setting Legacy Option ROMs to Disabled, the next boot was without issue. However, the second reboot yields a blank screen. No Dell logo on either integrated or NVIDIA graphics. I had to remove the graphics card in order to access the BIOS via the integrated graphics in order to set Legacy Option ROMs back to Enabled, then reinstalling the card works as expected.

Is there any way to accomplish what I wanted to do?

Comment: What model is the graphics card?

Comment: If your graphics card has only a BIOS option ROM but not an EFI compatible one, then disabling "legacy" option ROMs will stop card initialization on boot, which results in an unusable card.

Comment: Are you sure Windows was installed on a GPT partition?  The fact Legacy Mode was disabled is an indication it was not.  That means enabling UEFI only mode will not be possible.

Comment: @Mokubai MSI GTX 1060. I'll update my question.

Comment: @EugenRieck I considered that, but I tried it in another desktop (Also a Dell XPS, but one that shipped with a different graphics card) and it has no issues with Legacy Option ROMs set to Disabled (and Firmware TPM set to Enabled). Also, the first boot after Legacy Option ROMs is set to Disabled does work.

Comment: @Ramhound I have been booting UEFI this whole time. When I set Legacy Option ROMs to Disabled, I am unable to reach F2 or F12 when I have the graphics card installed, but have no issue booting with the integrated graphics.

Comment: @Mooseman - I asked you to confirm if Windows was actually installed on a GPT partition.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. I confirmed through Disk Management.

Comment: Update: With only integrated graphics, I have no issue turning on secure boot altogether, which includes UEFI, Legacy Option ROMs Disabled, and Firmware TPM Enabled.